# Perform an action when bluetooth keyboard is connected or disconnected

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, script

I am trying to write a script that can detect when a bluetooth keyboard is connected or disconnected from my mac and perform an action. The keyboard is a Logitech MX but I don't want my script to be dependent of that.

I can use bash, applescript, C, or any other language that can be called/binded to node.js

Comment: It‘s unclear what exactly you are struggling with here (how to write scripts on general, how to detect a Bluetooth device, how to get triggered in case of connection, how to execute something based the trigger). Also, from looking at the comment beneath the answer, it seems to be rather a software development question which is more on-topic on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

The app [Tooth Fairy](https://c-command.com/toothfairy/) ($5.99) should be able to do this. Although it's designed for AirPods, it works just as well with keyboards and other Bluetooth devices. After adding a device, you can set scripts to run upon connect and disconnect, so you can call your own scripts to perform whatever action you'd like to take.

[image: Tooth Fairy advanced settings menu]

Comment: I don't want to and can't depend on an app, I need to do this programatically.